# Why does Entity Framework Core generate HashSet?

Tags: c#, sql-server, api, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

Why does Entity Framework Core generate a `HashSet` if my entity has no relation to another entity?

I get the following error

> A possible object cycle was detected which is not supported. This can either be due to a cycle or if the object depth is larger than the maximum allowed depth of 32

For my model is cycled and I get null in the navigation properties.

My entity created by EF Core:

```
public partial class Customers
{
    public Customers()
    {
        Orders = new HashSet<Orders>();
    }

    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Street { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string ZipCode { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Orders> Orders { get; set; }
}
```

`Orders` entity:

```
public partial class Orders
{
    public Orders()
    {
        OrderItems = new HashSet<OrderItems>();
    }

    public int OrderId { get; set; }
    public int? CustomerId { get; set; }
    public byte OrderStatus { get; set; }
    public DateTime OrderDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime RequiredDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime? ShippedDate { get; set; }
    public int StoreId { get; set; }
    public int StaffId { get; set; }

    public virtual Customers Customer { get; set; }
    public virtual Staffs Staff { get; set; }
    public virtual Stores Store { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<OrderItems> OrderItems { get; set; }
}
```

My database schema:

```
CREATE TABLE [sales].[customers]
(
    [customer_id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [first_name] [varchar](255) NOT NULL,
    [last_name] [varchar](255) NOT NULL,
    [phone] [varchar](25) NULL,
    [email] [varchar](255) NOT NULL,
    [street] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [city] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [state] [varchar](25) NULL,
    [zip_code] [varchar](5) NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([customer_id] ASC)
                WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
                      IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
                      ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE TABLE [sales].[orders]
(
    [order_id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [customer_id] [int] NULL,
    [order_status] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
    [order_date] [date] NOT NULL,
    [required_date] [date] NOT NULL,
    [shipped_date] [date] NULL,
    [store_id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [staff_id] [int] NOT NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([order_id] ASC)
                WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
                      IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
                      ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [sales].[orders] WITH CHECK 
    ADD FOREIGN KEY([customer_id])
        REFERENCES [sales].[customers] ([customer_id])
        ON UPDATE CASCADE
        ON DELETE CASCADE
GO

ALTER TABLE [sales].[orders] WITH CHECK 
    ADD FOREIGN KEY([staff_id])
        REFERENCES [sales].[staffs] ([staff_id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [sales].[orders] WITH CHECK 
    ADD FOREIGN KEY([store_id])
        REFERENCES [sales].[stores] ([store_id])
        ON UPDATE CASCADE
        ON DELETE CASCADE
GO
```

Comment: I change the class images

Comment: @DaleK I uploaded DLL

Comment: @DaleK lo siento amigo, yo no sabia como aceptar sus cambios. He corregido nuevamente.

Comment: `if my entity has no relation to another entity.` Your question clearly shows there _is_ a relation / FK.

Comment: But why clients have an ICollection <Orders> Orders if the relation has Orders to client.
An order has only one customer. But in the model created by EF Core, client can have many orders. Actually, that automatically generated model does not work for me since it generates an exception for so many nested objects and it is not really the model as it creates my relationships in the database.

Comment: Which exact line of code throws the exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is due to problems with circular references and this was the solution for my project using Asp Net Core 5, ignore the circular references.

Credits: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/28286

Answer (score 1):

- The HashSet in the constructor is not compulsory, it aims to help you avoid **NullReferenceExceptions** when no records are fetched from the database.
- You can use other Collection types, but I believe HashSet is appropriate in most of the case.

Comment: What I don't understand is because EF Core creates a property "ICollection <Orders> Orders" if in my database model it is not indicated that way.

Comment: If you intend to make the relationship between table Customers and table Orders is one-to-one, you must also indicate the FK column **order_id** in the table Custo

Comment: Now looking at your schema, I think the relationship between table Customers and Orders are one-to-many, that's why EF Core auto generates the field  **public virtual ICollection<Orders> Orders**

Comment: I think I understood. My database approach is correct. But is there some way to tell EF not to set the collection that refers to a "One to many" relation (A client can have multiple orders). Is that possible without removing it manually?

Comment: Automatically create entities with the following instruction "dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold" MY_CON_STRING "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer --output-dir Entities \ Test --schema production --schema sales --context-dir Repositories --context SijDbPrueba"

Comment: I think you must do it manually. Is there an error if you delete the collection field?

Comment: Thanks everyone, researching my answer has to do with Lazy and Eager Loading. I have added "include" to fix it. Later I had problems with circular references and this was the solution for my project using AspnetCore 5 ignore the circular references https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/28286